# How to convert HTML-ENTITIES and preg_replace in PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm trying to convert `&nbsp;` to `whitespace`.

and then use `preg_replace` to do some Regex.

like this.

```
$title = "&nbsp;TEST&nbsp;Ok.2-2";
$title = mb_convert_encoding($title, 'UTF-8', 'HTML-ENTITIES');
//$title = html_entity_decode($title, ENT_NOQUOTES, 'UTF-8');
//( MEAN: I can use mb_convert_encoding() or html_entity_decode())
//GOT the same out put = TEST < Ok.2-2.

//So now I have TEST < Ok.2-2
//I want to make a space on Ok so I use preg_replace()
$replace = "~\s+(ok[.]?)~i";
$title = preg_replace($replace, ' OK. ', $title, -1);
$title = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $title);
$title = trim($title);

//The result = TEST < Ok.2-2 (not work!)
echo($title);
```

with this code the `mb_convert_encoding` and `html_entity_decode` is work well but when I try to use `preg_replace` to regex the whitespace it seem it not found the whitespace that converted.

Now out put: `TEST < Ok.2-2`

Expected out put: `TEST < OK. 2-2`

**NOW MY SOLUTION**

I added the `str_replace` to hardcode replace a `&nbsp;` to whitespace
and use mb_convert_encoding or html_entity_decode to convert another htmlentity.

```
$title = '&nbsp;TEST&nbsp;&lt;&nbsp;Ok.2-2';
$title = str_replace('&nbsp;', ' ', $title);
$title = mb_convert_encoding($title, 'UTF-8', 'HTML-ENTITIES');
//$title = html_entity_decode($title, ENT_NOQUOTES, 'UTF-8');
//( MEAN: I can use mb_convert_encoding() or html_entity_decode())
//GOT the same out put = TEST < Ok.2-2.

//So now I have TEST < Ok.2-2
//I want to make a space on Ok so I use preg_replace()
$replace = '~\s+(ok[.]?)~i';
$title = preg_replace($replace, ' OK. ', $title, -1);
$title = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $title);
$title = trim($title);

//The result TEST < OK. 2-2 (WORK!)
echo($title);
```

NOW my out put: `TEST < OK. 2-2`

MY expected: `TEST < OK. 2-2`

Any suggestion for best solution?

Comment: Expected output should be `TEST OK.2-2` i.e. no space between `.` and `2`

Comment: Is `&nbsp;` an example or literally the only one you need to convert? If not will they all be named, or are hex and decimal also expected?

Comment: Try change the double quotes to single quotes. `'~\s+(ok[.]?)~'`

Comment: @Tushar I edited the new expected out put.

Comment: @sln I try to change to single quotes but not work.

Comment: @chris85 I'd like to convert another html entity too.

Comment: As I stated the the `html_entity_decode` you have commented out should work. What is the other entity you are trying to pass? Could you please update the question with your exact issue/needs?

Comment: @chris85, Thanks now I'm edited my question and add some htmlentity maybe need to convert. Sorry for make you confuse.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will give you what you are after.

```
$title = trim(
     preg_replace('~\s+~', ' ', 
          str_ireplace(array('&nbsp;', ' ok.'), array(' ', ' OK. '), 
     "&nbsp;TEST&nbsp;Ok.2-2")
     )
);
```

This will:

1. Strip leading and trailing white spaces (`trim`)
2. Replace multiple white spaces with a single white space (`preg_replace('~\s+~', ' '`)
3. Replace `&nbsp;` to a single space (`str_ireplace`)
4. Replace `ok.` case insensitive to `OK.` (`str_ireplace`)

Output:

> TEST OK. 2-2

Your HTML entity decode example is correct, http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/eed7e30d507f7197585f29c1fdde9e7744fc572d

```
$title = html_entity_decode("&nbsp;TEST&nbsp;Ok.2-2", ENT_NOQUOTES, 'UTF-8');
echo $title;
```

Output:

> TEST Ok.2-2

Edit:

```
<?php
$title = '&nbsp;TEST&nbsp;&lt;&nbsp;Ok.2-2';
$title = trim(preg_replace('~\s+~', ' ', str_ireplace(array('&nbsp;', '&lt;', 'Ok.'), array(' ', '', ' OK. '), $title)));
echo $title;
```

It's probably safer to just remove the 2 entities with the str_replace. If your string were `<h1>&nbsp;TEST&nbsp;&lt;&nbsp;Ok.2-2</h1>` and you decoded then removed all `<` your string would not function as it had.

Output:

> TEST OK. 2-2

Comment: Thanks, @chris85 for help. but I use `html_entity_decode` because I'd like to decode another html entity too. As you suggest I think will I use `str_replace('&nbsp;', ' ', $title);` is better idea?

Comment: That was just for the one entity, if you're going to have more you should use the function. What entity isn't working? I see you updated your question a bit but not the code, did your code not change? Did the above code not work?